# nested reference can be accessible from dotnet core 1

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core, architecture

I have created Business and DataAccess Layer for my web project using dotnet core.
I have added Data access reference in Business layer and referenced the business layer in UI (web project) layer.

I seen, I am able to access my Data access layer from my UI (web) project. I am really wondering, It can lead to violation of any application design.

Appreciate help, if anybody come across this and how to restrict access to data access layer from UI.

[image]

Comment: The simple solution is: Just don't do that. Just rely on Dependency Injection, I don't see you doing that yet.

Comment: Answers from MVC team - https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6635

Comment: Same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160274/project-references-in-net-core-different-from-previous-net-versions i prefer to have it separate as well to avoid mistakes but it seems that is not longer how things work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an indirect dependency is a dependency too.

And your toplevel (MVC) project has to reference everything, direct or indirect, in order to get all modules loaded. And to set up the dependency injection.

You can get better separation by introducing an interfaces layer in a separate project. For example IBusinessClass and IDataAccessClass.

That works for everything but the main project so if you want this particular  separation from your example, move your Controllers to a separate project and depend that on the IBusiness interfaces only. Though I'm not sure how that works with MVC's conventions.

Comment: To register the dependency, we need corresponding concrete classes to be accessible (should be public). Even though we says we are resolving through dependency, there are chances where i can create direct dependency with concrete classes.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with "to set up the dependency injection". You could avoid even that when you can find/create something similar to MEF for .Core. But I wouldn't bother.